# Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError okio.Okio

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway, okio

I have integrated paypal service in my application using

```
try {
    //PayPal
    Intent intent = new Intent(VODActivity.this, PayPalService.class);
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
    startService(intent);
    //PayPal
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And application gradle file is looks like :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'me.drakeet.materialdialog:library:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'se.simbio.encryption:library:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.daasuu:animateHorizontalProgressBar:0.2.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    // Loader
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.michaelye.easydialog:easydialog:1.4'
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    **compile('com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.13.0') {
        exclude group: 'io.card'//disable the card io feature for scanning card
    }**
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev171-1.22.0'
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile files('libs/mediaplayersdk.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'

}
```

It was working completely find till yesterday evening. but suddenly it was getting crash caused by **"Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError okio.Okio"**

Anyone can help in that...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if i am run this same line by commenting the paypal service.. application is running completely.

Comment: did u try clean + rebuild?

Comment: @howdoidothis yes..

Comment: Try adding `compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.8.0'` then

Comment: @howdoidothis already tried with this also... but still the same issue